# Find out tags with no wiki?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

Is it possible to find out the tags that are old and have no tag wiki?

Wouldn't it be good to find out the tags without it and possibly have a proper wiki for them?
It would improve the tags a lot IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [this data explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/94920/most-common-tags-with-missing-wiki). Or just sift through [the tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) and filter out stuff with excerpts.

Comment: How can one filter out tags with excerpts on the Tags page?

Comment: @DannyBeckett: you can't

Comment: Ah, ok, I took your answer literally.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you'll find the majority of the tags that don't have a wiki are newly added ones.

On that basis, you can order the tags by [newest](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new) in order to locate the newly added ones, which are listed without a description.